# how to show calendar in shell scripting in 2 columns only?

Tags: shell, command

how to show calendar in shell scripting in 2 columns only (by default it is in spitted into 3 columns)
Here is the image of by default command :  `cal`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using for instance

```
cal -n 2 3 2021
```

you get the output for March and April next to each other. If you do this for each odd-numbered month, you get the result you want to achieve.

Comment: I want whole Year Calendar

Comment: That's why I wrote _If you do this for each odd-numbered month, you get the result you want to achieve._ . Basic math: One invocation of `cal` according to my proposal gives you 2 months. There are 6 odd-numbered months in the year. In total this gives you 12 months, which is as close to a whole year as you can get ....